# How do I group my date variable into month/year in R?

Tags: r

I have a "date" vector, that contains dates in mm/dd/yyyy format:

```
 head(Entered_Date,5)
[1] 1/5/1998 1/5/1998 1/5/1998 1/5/1998 1/5/1998
```

I am trying to plot a frequency variable against the date, but I want to group the dates that it is by month or year. As it is now, there is a frequency per day, but I want to plot the frequency by month or year. So instead of having a frequency of 1 for 1/5/1998, 1 for 1/7/1998, and 3 for 1/8/1998, I would like to display it as 5 for 1/1998. It is a relatively large data set, with dates from 1998 to present, and I would like to find some automated way to accomplish this.

```
> dput(head(Entered_Date))
structure(c(260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L, 260L), .Label = c("1/1/1998", 
"1/1/1999", "1/1/2001", "1/1/2002", "1/10/2000", "1/10/2001", 
"1/10/2002", "1/10/2003", "1/10/2005", "1/10/2006", "1/10/2007", 
"1/10/2008", "1/10/2011", "1/10/2012", "1/10/2013", "1/11/1999", 
"1/11/2000", "1/11/2001", "1/11/2002", "1/11/2005", "1/11/2006", 
"1/11/2008", "1/11/2010", "1/11/2011", "1/11/2012", "1/11/2013", 
"1/12/1998", "1/12/1999", "1/12/2001", "1/12/2004", "1/12/2005", ...
```

Comment: To be sure of reproducible results, please post the output of `dput(head(Entered_Date))`

Comment: Have a look at `as.yearmon` from the `zoo` package.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Here is an example using `dplyr`.  You simply use the corresponding date format string for month `%m` or year `%Y` in the `format` statement.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(from =as.Date("01/01/1998", "%d/%m/%Y"), 
                                 to=as.Date("01/01/2000", "%d/%m/%Y"), by="day"),
                 value = sample(seq(5), 731, replace = TRUE))

head(df)
        date value
1 1998-01-01     2
2 1998-01-02     4
3 1998-01-03     3
4 1998-01-04     5
5 1998-01-05     5
6 1998-01-06     1

library(dplyr)

df %>%
mutate(month = format(date, "%m"), year = format(date, "%Y")) %>%
group_by(month, year) %>%
summarise(total = sum(value))

Source: local data frame [25 x 3]
Groups: month [?]

   month  year total
   (chr) (chr) (int)
1     01  1998   105
2     01  1999    91
3     01  2000     3
4     02  1998    74
5     02  1999    77
6     03  1998    96
7     03  1999    86
8     04  1998    91
9     04  1999    95
10    05  1998    93
..   ...   ...   ...
```

Comment: one thing, how do I get the month to show up as the name of the month instead of the number?

Comment: @Learning_R you need to provide a complete reproducible set of your data.  Your `dput` is cut off so I can't get your data to reproduce this label problem where my example does provide the names.

Comment: @Learning_R, take a subset and take a `dput` of that.  Make sure you can reproduce the error on the subset.

Comment: Also, I need it by month/year, not just the same month across all years

Comment: Sorry, I am very new to all of this and I am struggling

Comment: @Learning_R, see edit for grouping by month & year.  `dplyr` is a good package to look in to.  It makes a  lot of summaries simpler.

Comment: @Learning_R, if you are satisfied with this or another answer, please be sure to accept one so the questions is marked as answered.

Comment: I always use something like 
`df %>%
mutate(date2 = format(date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
group_by(date2) %>%
summarise(total = sum(value)) `

Answer (score 82):

The `floor_date()` function from the `lubridate` package does this nicely.

```
data %>% 
    group_by(month = lubridate::floor_date(date, "month")) %>%
    summarize(summary_variable = sum(value))
```

Thanks to Roman Cheplyaka
https://ro-che.info/articles/2017-02-22-group_by_month_r

See more on how to use the function: https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/round_date.html

Comment: This is the best answer - I've seen. It's near impossible to keep the field as a date as oppose to a character

Comment: I think so. it's not a good idea that make date as character, especially data are large.

Comment: Excellent! This I guess is the direct equivalent to doing `TRUNC(to_date(a.wh_prces_dte), 'MON')` in ORACLE/SQL.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add to @cdeterman answer, you can use `lubridate` along with `dplyr` to make this even easier:

```
df <- data.frame(date = seq.Date(from =as.Date("01/01/1998", "%d/%m/%Y"), 
                                 to=as.Date("01/01/2000", "%d/%m/%Y"), by="day"),
                 value = sample(seq(5), 731, replace = TRUE))

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
mutate(month = month(date), year = year(date)) %>%
group_by(month, year) %>%
summarise(total = sum(value))
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you just add a column in your data like this:

`Year <- format(as.Date(Entered_Date, "%d/%m/%Y"), "%Y")`

Comment: Change the last bit before the parenthesis to "%m/%Y"... `?strptime` will give you a key to all these date formatting options.

Answer (score 2):

Dont need `dplyr`. Look at `?as.POSIXlt`

```
df$date<-as.POSIXlt(df$date)
mon<-df$date$mon
yr<-df$date$year
monyr<-as.factor(paste(mon,yr,sep="/"))
df$date<-monyr
```

Don't need to use `ggplot2` but its nice for this kind of thing.

```
c <- ggplot(df, aes(factor(date)))
c + geom_bar()
```

If you want to see the actual numbers

```
aggregate(. ~ date,data = df,FUN=length )
df2<-aggregate(. ~ date,data = df,FUN=length )
df2
    date value
1   0/98    31
2   0/99    31
3   1/98    28
4   1/99    28
5  10/98    30
6  10/99    30
7  11/97     1
8  11/98    31
9  11/99    31
10  2/98    31
11  2/99    31
12  3/98    30
13  3/99    30
14  4/98    31
15  4/99    31
16  5/98    30
17  5/99    30
18  6/98    31
19  6/99    31
20  7/98    31
21  7/99    31
22  8/98    30
23  8/99    30
24  9/98    31
25  9/99    31
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a super easy way using the cut() function:

```
    list = as.Date(c("1998-5-2", "1993-4-16", "1998-5-10"))
    cut(list, breaks = "month")
```

and you will get this:

```
    [1] 1998-05-01 1993-04-01 1998-05-01
    62 Levels: 1993-04-01 1993-05-01 1993-06-01 1993-07-01 1993-08-01 ... 1998-05-01
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is `slider::slide_period`:

```r
library(slider)
library(dplyr)

monthly_summary <- function(data) summarise(data, date = format(max(date), "%Y-%m"), value = sum(value))
slide_period_dfr(df, df$date, "month", monthly_summary)

      date value
1  1998-01    92
2  1998-02    82
3  1998-03   113
4  1998-04    94
5  1998-05    92
6  1998-06    74
7  1998-07    89
8  1998-08    92
9  1998-09    91
10 1998-10   100
...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also `group_by(month_yr = cut(date, breaks = "1 month")` in base R, without needing to use lubridate or other packages.