# Plot Monthly or Annualy in R having a Time Series data like YYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

Tags: r, plot, time-series

I have a time series like this:

```
created_time,reaction_counts
2016-01-18T08:05:44+0000,65
2016-01-18T08:05:44+0000,65
2016-01-18T08:05:44+0000,65
2016-02-23T01:42:48+0000,468
2016-02-23T03:51:37+0000,125
2016-02-23T09:49:01+0000,433
2016-02-23T10:09:32+0000,72
2016-02-26T07:45:10+0000,137
2016-02-26T11:48:09+0000,120
2016-02-27T03:27:39+0000,70
2016-02-28T09:28:16+0000,145
2016-03-02T00:17:14+0000,122
2016-03-02T05:34:41+0000,108
2016-03-02T09:04:45+0000,296
```

And I want to aggregate it by month (and also by year) and plot a histogram.
How do I do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Surely this has been asked and answered many times on SO. Have you done any searching? If so use the SO [edit] facilities to add the terms did you use and what links you found that you were having diffidculty applying to this problem. (You should also indicate what function or functions you desire for aggregation, ... `sum`, `mean`, or `sd` would be typical responses.) And if that is data you have already entered into a data structure then look at the question entitled: "How to make a great reproducible example in R" so you can post a proper R object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I group my date variable into month/year in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221425/how-do-i-group-my-date-variable-into-month-year-in-r)

Comment: But my date is like this: YYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS

Comment: convert your date from character to date format with the lubridate package and `ymd_hms()` function -> `mutate_at(df, "created_time", ymd_hms)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code for converting hourly data to monthly or yearly data

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(hydroTSM)

try <- structure(list(created_time = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L), .Label = c("2016-01-18T08:05:44+0000", 
"2016-02-23T01:42:48+0000", "2016-02-23T03:51:37+0000", "2016-02-23T09:49:01+0000", 
"2016-02-23T10:09:32+0000", "2016-02-26T07:45:10+0000", "2016-02-26T11:48:09+0000", 
"2016-02-27T03:27:39+0000", "2016-02-28T09:28:16+0000", "2016-03-02T00:17:14+0000", 
"2016-03-02T05:34:41+0000", "2016-03-02T09:04:45+0000"), class = "factor"), 
    reaction_counts = c(65L, 65L, 65L, 468L, 125L, 433L, 72L, 
    137L, 120L, 70L, 145L, 122L, 108L, 296L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))

df <- mutate_at(try, "created_time", ymd_hms)
```

### Monthly conversion

```
monthly = df %>%
  mutate(month = format(created_time, "%m"), year = format(created_time, "%Y")) %>%
  group_by(month, year) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(reaction_counts))
```

### For histogram plotting of monthly data

```
hist(monthly$total)
```

### Yearly conversion

```
yearly = df %>%
  mutate(month = format(created_time, "%m"), year = format(created_time, "%Y")) %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(reaction_counts))
```

### For histogram plotting of yearly data

```
hist(yearly$total)
```