# Trying to sum deaths per month, year in r

Tags: r

I'm very much a beginner in r.

I have a "date" vector in the following format:

```
head(z$dod)
[1] "2017-08-15" "2017-08-21" "2017-08-20" "2017-08-22" "2017-08-31"
[6] "2017-09-04"
```

And I have a binary variable; 1 for measles and 0 for non-measles death for each of these dates.

I would like to sum the frequency of measles deaths per month, year (i.e. drop the days in my dates) and plot it. I've tried various approaches such as cutting it into breaks by "month" or as below:

```
z$dod<-as.POSIXlt(z$dod, format="%d-%m-%Y")
mon<-z$dod$mon
yr<-z$dod$year
mon_yr<-as.factor(paste(mon, yr, sep="/"))
z$dod<-mon_yr

c <- ggplot(z, aes(factor(dod)))
c + geom_bar()
```

or try and aggregate:

```
measledeath.mon_yr <- aggregate(z$measledeath, by=list(z$mon_yr), sum) 
colnames(measledeath.mon_yr) <- c('date', 'deaths')
```

but none have provided what I'm looking for so far. What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: First you should create a new column `yrmon` that represents the date column from `d-m-Y` to 'm-Y'. You can use the zoo package to get the desired conversion from date to yearmon.  Then you should try to aggregate by `yrmon`.

Comment: This post might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221425/how-do-i-group-my-date-variable-into-month-year-in-r

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `dplyr` and `lubridate`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(year = year(date),
         month = month(date),
         year_mon = paste(year, month, sep = "-")) %>% 
  group_by(year_mon) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(measles)))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  year_mon   sum
  <chr>    <dbl>
1 2017-10     12
2 2017-8       5
3 2017-9      20
```

---

*Data*

```
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(17399, 17400, 17401, 17402, 
17403, 17404, 17405, 17406, 17407, 17408, 17409, 17410, 17411, 
17412, 17413, 17414, 17415, 17416, 17417, 17418, 17419, 17420, 
17421, 17422, 17423, 17424, 17425, 17426, 17427, 17428, 17429, 
17430, 17431, 17432, 17433, 17434, 17435, 17436, 17437, 17438, 
17439, 17440, 17441, 17442, 17443, 17444, 17445, 17446, 17447, 
17448, 17449, 17450, 17451, 17452, 17453, 17454, 17455, 17456, 
17457, 17458, 17459, 17460), class = "Date"), measles = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-62L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

in Base-R we can use `sapply` and `split` and `format` together like this

```
> z
       dates measledeath
1 2017-08-15           1
2 2017-08-21           2
3 2017-08-20           3
4 2017-08-22           4
5 2017-09-30           5



sapply(split(z$measledeath,format(z$dates, format = "%Y-%m")), sum)

2017-08 2017-09 
     10       5
```

Edit, Dates must be in `as.Date` format.

---

Data:

```
z <- data.frame(    
        dates=as.Date(c("2017-08-15", "2017-08-21", "2017-08-20", "2017-08-22", "2017-09-30")),
        measledeath = c(1,2,3,4,5))
```