# Group by weekly data and summarize by month in R with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, tidyverse, lubridate

I have a [dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11KhBiLT5O2vbv1D2ZHqXkf42tjlaKlW1a7RYoQlsRN4/edit?usp=sharing) of weekly mortgage rate data.

The data looks very simple:

```
library(tibble)
library(lubridate)

df <- tibble(
  Date = as_date(c("2/7/2008 ", "2/14/2008", "2/21/2008", "2/28/2008", "3/6/2008"), format = "%m/%d/%Y"),
  Rate = c(5.67, 5.72, 6.04, 6.24, 6.03)
)
```

I am trying to group it and summarize by month.

This [blogpost](https://ro-che.info/articles/2017-02-22-group_by_month_r) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221425/how-do-i-group-my-date-variable-into-month-year-in-r) are not what I want, because they just add the month column.

They give me the output:

```
month         Date     summary_variable
2008-02-01  2008-02-07  5.67        
2008-02-01  2008-02-14  5.72        
2008-02-01  2008-02-21  6.04        
2008-02-01  2008-02-28  6.24
```

My desired output (ideally the last day of the month):

```
Month  Average rate
2/28/2008   6
3/31/2008   6.1
4/30/2008   5.9
```

**In the output above I put random numbers, not real calculations.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can get the month extracted as column and do a group by mean

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)
df1 %>%
  group_by(Month = as.Date(as.yearmon(mdy(DATE)), 1)) %>% 
  summarise(Average_rate = mean(MORTGAGE30US))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 151 x 2
#   Month      Average_rate
#   <date>            <dbl>
# 1 2008-02-29         5.92
# 2 2008-03-31         5.97
# 3 2008-04-30         5.92
# 4 2008-05-31         6.04
# 5 2008-06-30         6.32
# 6 2008-07-31         6.43
# 7 2008-08-31         6.48
# 8 2008-09-30         6.04
# 9 2008-10-31         6.2 
#10 2008-11-30         6.09
# … with 141 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and efforts! The output is the same as I posted above. It is not what I need :(

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker in the post you described that it should be the last day of the month.  My update does that

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker I have a difficultly in understanding whether the expected output is based on the full dataset showed or the example you gave as iinput.  If it is the example in your post. you don't have the April data

Comment: Please use the full data, if you can.

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker I tried your original data.  For the first data point, I get 5.92 as average instead of 6.  Can you show your calculation

Comment: No, that was just example! Please disregard that! :)

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker if that is the case, it is giving me the expected

Comment: Your output looks perfect, trying to replicate it!

Comment: The last day of the month in your expected output is `2/28/2008` when it should be `2/29/2008` as provided in @akrun's solution.

Comment: @akrun, you nailed it! Thanks a ton.

Comment: Why zoo package called?

Comment: @AnilGoyal It is for the `as.yearmon`