# How to find probability of dataset in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset with something like that, below is a small part. How to use barplot to calculate to probability of raining by month?

```
Date           Rain Today
2020-01-01     Yes
2020-01-02     No
2020-01-03     Yes
2020-01-04     Yes
2020-01-05     No
...            ...
2020-12-31     Yes
```

Comment: How would you use a scatter plot to estimate the probability?

Comment: My mistake, i want it as a bar plot

Comment: try constructing a `month` variable (e.g. `month <- format(df$Date, "%m")`) and then using `prop.table(table(df$Rain, df$month))` ... ?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Correct answer in the comments

I dont know why you would want to use a scatterplot for this, but, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221425/how-do-i-group-my-date-variable-into-month-year-in-r) post, you can use `dplyr` pipelines to do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(month = format(Date, "%Y-%m")) %>%
  summarise(probability = mean(`Rain Today` == 'Yes'))
```

To group your data into months and find out how many days it has rained/not rained. Then you find the mean of how many days it has rained.

Thank you everyone in the comments for pointing it out. I hope this helps

Comment: probability cannever be length.

Comment: How about `probability = mean(`Rain Value`=="Yes")` ?

Comment: `df %>% group_by(month = format(Date, "%Y-%m")) %>%summarise(probability = mean(\`Rain Today\` == 'Yes'))`

Answer (score 0):

The `lubridate` package has some great functions that help you deal with dates.

```
install.packages("lubridate")
df$month <- lubridate::month(df$Date)
tapply(df[,"Rain Today"]=="Yes", df$month, mean)
```

You may need to execute `df$Date <- as.Date(as.Date)` first if it's currently stored as `character`rather than a date.

If you don't want to have any dependencies, then I think you can get what you want like this:

```
df$month <- substr(df$Date, start=6, stop=7) #Get the 6th and 7th characters of your date strings, which correspond to the "month" part
tapply(df[,"Rain Today"]=="Yes", df$month, mean)
```