# How to group data by month in R with dplyr

Tags: r, date, dplyr, group-by

How can I group my data by month (y%,m%,d%), then create a table with a count of how many rows are in each month?
Date is in column “orderdate”.

So what I’m looking for is 01= 35744, 02= 747362, etc

All in a new table

I have gotten data arranged by date, but not month specifically. So current grouped and filtered table is Example_Table

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I group my date variable into month/year in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221425/how-do-i-group-my-date-variable-into-month-year-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `lubridate::date` and simple `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

dummy <- data.frame(
  orderdate = seq(as.Date("2020-01-02"),as.Date("2021-07-13"), by = "days")
)

dummy %>%
  as_tibble %>%
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(orderdate)) %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  summarise(n = n())

   month     n
   <dbl> <int>
 1     1    61
 2     2    57
 3     3    62
 4     4    60
 5     5    62
 6     6    60
 7     7    44
 8     8    31
 9     9    30
10    10    31
11    11    30
12    12    31
```

as table

```
dummy2 <- dummy %>%
  as_tibble %>%
  mutate(month = lubridate::month(orderdate)) %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  select(n) %>%
  t %>%
  as.table
colnames(dummy2) <- seq(1:12)
dummy2

   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
n 61 57 62 60 62 60 44 31 30 31 30 31
```

Comment: Great! Thanks! Any idea how to make this response into a table?

Comment: @Brennan I edit my code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have data for multiple years do you count each month separately ? Meaning June 2020 should be captured separately from June 2021.

If so, you can use

```
library(dplyr)

result <- Example_Table %>% count(month = format(orderdate, '%b-%Y'))
```

Or in base R -

```
result <- table(format(Example_Table$orderdate, '%b-%Y'))
```

If you want to consider June 2020 and June 2021 in the same group use only `'%b'` in `format` instead of `'%b-%Y'`.

Comment: Having this information changes so many things in my journey. Thank you!